# Reformat bootstrap datepicker on form submit js

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, format

I have a bootstrap datepicker I use that has this formatting:

```
$('#dp2').datepicker({
            format: "MM,d,yyyy - DD",
            orientation: "top",
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true
        });
```

This will output a friendly readable date like this:
July,26,2017 - Wednesday

however when I submit my form I want the date to be formatted in a date like this so it can play nice with the mysql database:
07/26/2017

What can I do to reformat the date to what I need upon a form submit ( i got the form submit working just need to know how to reformat the date upon form submit)

I am using Bootstrap's datepicker.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try formatting the date object like this:

```
var date = $('#dp2').datepicker('getDate');
var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
```

Update: With bootstrap's datepicker use:

```
var date = $('#dp2').datepicker('getDate');
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply but i am getting this: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined. I tried creating a jsfiddle but cant seem to get the date picker to work properly so im sorry for that. Any ideas on what I can do to try and solve this error?
fyi my output for the date var is: Wed Jul 26 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddle! There is no doubt that what your telling me to do works. However there is something about my code that is still erroring out and throwing this: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined. I dont want to paste blobs of code but dont know what else to include in my question to allow you guys to replicate what I am seeing.

Comment: Ok just out of curiosity could this be that I am using bootstrap's datepicker? and not jquery ui's datepicker? Would this have anything to do with why I am seeing these errors? EDIT: I now see that I only mentioned bootstrap datepicker in my title and no where in my question do I say I am using bootstrap datepicker, I am sorry for this, I updated my question to be more clear :)

Comment: Ah, that would be it. Let me look into bootstrap's datepicker real quick.

Comment: Bootstrap's datepicker doesn't seem to have a format method, but we can do it ourselves: https://jsfiddle.net/5qxu7nL9/4/

Comment: Wow cant believe they dont have a format method! I guess this is a reason why I am having so much trouble with it. Thank you so much for taking the time and effort putting into this! This works great for me now! :) I'm marking this is as the answer. Thank you so much for your time!